# $ is not a function, although jQuery is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

Take a look at this site:

http://www.magiskecirkel.no/

It says $ is not a function, although jQuery is loaded.

I know I have asked this question before, and it was fixed, but now apparently the problem is back... So sorry for re-posting, and thanks for all help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, the last line of your jQuery file is the following:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

See [`jQuery.noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noconflict) for what this does.

To get around it, you can use the following way of doing document ready:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // use jQuery with the $ symbol
});
```

Alternatively, remove that line from jQuery.js if you can.

Comment: do you need to wrap the ready callback with (function($){ })(jQuery); or is this a built in feature of jQuery that the first param to the ready callback is, in fact, jQuery?

Comment: no don't remove anything from jQuery.js that's bad advice then you have to make that mod every time you make an upgrade

Comment: @mcgrailm It's a modified file anyway. That line doesn't exist in the original jQuery source file.

Comment: @Matt The latter -- [see the docs for the `ready` method](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: @lonesomeday sorry didn't notice that, still don't think thats good advice though

Comment: Excellent, it works! :-) Thanks to lonesomeday! If you run WP, check the jQuery noconflict wrappers section on this page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: @Helge No problem. It just occurred to me -- the other (v simple) solution is `window.$ = window.jQuery`.  This basically undoes `noConflict`. If you have further problems, that might be the silver bullet that solves everything :-)

Answer (score 1):

In global.js, can you change this line:

```
$(document).ready( function($) {
```

to:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

The error I get is on the line `$(document).ready( function($) {`  You don't need the $ in the function call.

Answer (score 0):

use [jQuery noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) when using with other libraries

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});
```